# Placing a div within body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend, appendto

Currently have my page setup as:

```
<body id="some-id">

   <div class="some-class">
   </div>
   <!-- some-class -->

</body>
```

I've tried using append and before, however, it's not quite doing what I want to do.

I'm trying to add a div with id `inserted-div` like this:

```
<body id="some-id">

<div id="inserted-div">

   <div class="some-class">
   </div>
   <!-- some-class -->

</div>
<!-- inserted div -->

</body>
```

Each time I use something, for example: `$('body').appendto("<div id='inserted-div'>");` it either won't insert or it will insert the `</div>` after the inserted <`div>` rather than placing the `</div>` before the closing body. Tried prepend and prependto but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `wrap` method.

```
$('.some-class').wrap('<div id="inserted-div"></div')
```

`$('body').prepend` -- will add a div as the first child of the body.

`$('body').append` -- will add a div as the last child of the body.

But in your case you want the `inserted-div` as a wrapper for an already existing div.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8WQY/)**

To target just the first instance you can either use

`$('.some-class').first()`  or `$('.some-class:eq(0)')`

Comment: That's right! completely forgot about wrap :) Only thing is it wraps body and I didn't want to wrap the `some-class` as it may change, that's why I wanted it inside `body` and wrapping all other content :)

Comment: Ok completely understand. Needs to wrap regardless.

Comment: How can I make it wrap only around the first found class (in case there are two of the same classes on the page)? `$('.some-class').first.wrap`?

Comment: `$('.some-class:eq(0)').wrap`  should do

Comment: Thanks Sushanth. Ok just testing your answer, it creates 2 `inserted-div`'s wrapped around each other and then wraps the `some-class` div?

Comment: Check the Fiddle in the post.. Works perfectly fine in the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap something around the entire body content, try:

```
$("body > *").wrapAll("<div id='inserted-div'/>");
```

If you want to wrap around the first DIV in the body:

```
$("body > div:eq(0)").wrap("<div id='inserted-div'/>");
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. But as above, for some reason it is creating the `inserted-div` twice?

Comment: Can you demonstrate in a fiddle?

Comment: Could be my own JS interrupting it. Fiddle would be quite long and I don't want to take up your time debugging my code.I'll set it in the header and see how it goes..